# Databricks Undefined function: iif. This function is neither a built-in/temporary function, nor a persistent function

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am getting the Databricks error suggesting that the method **iif** is not supported in Databricks. Therefore, can someone let me know what is the equivalent?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  
  *

FROM basecrmcbreport.account
LEFT OUTER JOIN basecrmcbreport.CRM2CBURL_Lookup
  ON account.Id = CRM2CBURL_Lookup.Key
LEFT OUTER JOIN basecrmcbreport.organizations
  ON CRM2CBURL_Lookup.CB_URL_KEY = organizations.cb_url
cross Join (values (charindex('://', homepage_url))) a(a)
cross Join (values (iif(a = 0, 1, a + 3))) b(b)
cross Join (values (charindex('/', homepage_url, b))) c(c)
cross Join (values (iif(c = 0, len(homepage_url) + 1, c))) d(d)
cross Join (values (substring(homepage_url, b, d - b))) e(e)
```

Comment: Just a if? https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/if.html

Comment: Hi Ferdyh, thanks for reaching out. Changing iff to just if, seemed to work. Can you let me know the equivalent of the len method:
```cross Join (values (if(c = 0, len(homepage_url) + 1, c))) d(d)```

Comment: Try length: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/length

Comment: Hi Saideep, the length function worked a treat, thank you. @ferdyh, both if and iff worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Saideep Arikontham and ferdyh, making it as an answer so it might help other community members.

> **Create a sample SQL table**

[image]

After that use below code for the length function.

```
 %sql
 SELECT * ,length(city) from df12
```

[image]